# For $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$, there is an integer within $|\{a\} - \{b\}|$ from $|a-b|.$

Tags: real-numbers, integers, fractional-part

> Let's take two real numbers $a,b$. The distance between $a$ and $b$ is $|a-b|$. Let $\{\}$ denote fractional part. Then for any $a$ and $b$, there is an integer close to $|a-b|$ which is at most  $|\{a\} - \{b\}|$ away from $|a-b|.$

We can see this intuitively but I just want to know what proof technique can be used and how to prove the above statement?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. I edited your post a bit for clarity. Typically we use dollar signs (\$) instead of quotes for math-mode.

Comment: Thank you Integrand!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We may assume that $a \leq b$, so that $| a - b | = b-a$. Consider $n = (b - \{b\}) - (a - \{a\})$. Then $n$ is an integer and we have $$|n - |a - b|| = |n - b + a| = |\{a\} - \{b\}|,$$ as desired.

Comment: @OP to make it explicit $n=\lfloor b\rfloor-\lfloor a\rfloor$.

Comment: Yeah! Got it Daniel and zwim